# Comment xml sections in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file that is containing several sections and I would need to comment 2 of them.
The file is like this:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
      <param-name>defaultContext</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
      <listener-class>MyListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
      <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
      <filter-class>filter.Filter1</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>type</param-name>
        <param-value>JSP</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter>
      <filter-name>Filter2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>filter.Filter2</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>type</param-name>
        <param-value>HTM</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter>
      <filter-name>Filter3</filter-name>
      <filter-class>filter.Filter3</filter-class>
  </filter>
</web-app>
```

In this example I need to comment the Filter1 and Filter3 sections. But it could be any of them, and not in a particular order, so I need to match the good section to be commented based on the filter name.
So the updated file would be:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
      <param-name>defaultContext</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
      <listener-class>MyListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <!--filter>
      <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
      <filter-class>filter.Filter1</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>type</param-name>
        <param-value>JSP</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter-->
  <filter>
      <filter-name>Filter2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>filter.Filter2</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>type</param-name>
        <param-value>HTM</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>
  <!--filter>
      <filter-name>Filter3</filter-name>
      <filter-class>filter.Filter3</filter-class>
  </filter-->
</web-app>
```

I have started to check the xml.dom.minidom to do this, but in fact I don't know how to locate precisely the Filter1 and Filter3 and how to comment the whole section including those two elements.
Basically I have started this code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

#Method to comment a node
def comment_node(node):
    comment = node.ownerDocument.createComment(node.toxml())
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(comment, node)
    return comment

#Parse the web.xml file
current_path = getcwd()
relative_file_path = r"webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml"
file_path = normpath(join(current_path, relative_file_path))
dom = minidom.parse(file_path)

#Search for filter sections
itemlist = dom.getElementsByTagName('filter-name')
for item in itemlist:
    if "Filter1" == item.nodeValue:
        #need to comment the whole node containing the filter-name
```

This is where I'm stuck.
Shall I search for all nodes 'filter' and then check if each one of them contains the good filter-name insead?

Please note that I am a beginner in Python, so I don't even know if I picked-up the good library here...

Could anyone help me to think of the good strategy to apply the change?

Thanks!

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, nor is it a tutorial site. There are many of those available. If you have specific problems implementing *actual code*, you'll probably have better luck finding assistance here, but general "I don't know how to do X, Y and Z so please tell me everything I need to know" questions are usually frowned upon.

Comment: I was probably not clear enough, my bad.
The thing is that I have found out how to parse the XML file, how to comment a section, but what I don't know is how to to be able to locate a specific element while parsing the xml and how to go back to the parent node to comment this one.
I keep on searching and trying things on my side, I'm not just waiting for someone to code it for me, but I'm rather searching for advice here, like maybe this is not the good method at all to implement my change.

Answer (score 1):

Just little modification

```
itemlist = dom.getElementsByTagName('filter-name')
for item in itemlist:
    if "Filter1" == item.childNodes[0].nodeValue:
        #need to comment the whole node containing the filter-name
        comment_node(item.parentNode)
print dom.toxml() # verif
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed the logic is quite simple in the end, I thought it would be more complicated...
I just get an issue to get the nodeValue, the method returning "none" I'll dig a bit
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Xendar David Zemens modify my post and add an error: the tag is not `filter` but `filter-name`

Comment: Yes I noticed that djangoliv, thanks!
I understood as well that the value of a tag is a child of this tag and not got through .nodeValue directly, that was not that clear in the API.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case of, here is the final version of my code. I added the writing to the xml file as it needs to be done manually (I thought in the beginning that the methods of the API where kind of pointers, so that the file was automatically updated!):

```
from os import getcwd
from os.path import normpath, join
from xml.dom import minidom

#Script explanation to the user
print("This script updates the web.xml file")
print()

#Method to comment a node
def comment_node(node):
    comment = node.ownerDocument.createComment(node.toxml())
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(comment, node)

#Parse the web.xml file
current_path = getcwd()
relative_file_path = r"webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml"
file_path = normpath(join(current_path, relative_file_path))
dom = minidom.parse(file_path)

#Search for filter sections
itemlist = dom.getElementsByTagName('filter')
for item in itemlist:
    for sub_item in item.childNodes:
        if "filter-name" == sub_item.nodeName:
            if "Filter1" == sub_item.childNodes[0].nodeValue or "Filter3" == sub_item.childNodes[0].nodeValue:
                #Need to comment the whole node containing the filter-name
                comment_node(item)
                #Stop looping on all the sub items as we already found the filter-name node
                break

# Should you want to see the result
print("Resulting file:")
print(dom.toxml())

#Writing to the file
file = open(file_path, 'w')
dom.writexml(file)
file.close()
```

Thanks a lot to @David Zemens and @djangoliv for their valuable help!

#### Update

Update suggested by @djangoliv, thanks!:

```
#itemlist = dom.getElementsByTagName('filter')
#for item in itemlist:
#   for sub_item in item.childNodes:
#       if "filter-name" == sub_item.nodeName:
#           if "Filter1" == sub_item.childNodes[0].nodeValue or "Filter3" == sub_item.childNodes[0].nodeValue:
#               #Need to comment the whole node containing the filter-name
#               comment_node(item)
#               #Stop looping on all the sub items as we already found the filter-name node
#               break
# more simple
itemlist = dom.getElementsByTagName('filter-name')
for item in itemlist:
    if item.childNodes[0].nodeValue in ["Filter1", "Filter3"]:
        comment_node(item.parentNode)
        break
```